# How to align misaligned p-table headers in angular after enabling the scroll?

Tags: header, scrollable, primeng-table, p-table

I am having a p-table with  and body. Before enabling the scroll, checkboxes in header and body and other header alignments were perfect. But after adding `[scrollable]=true` and `scrollHeight="200px"` to p-table tag, headers are misaligned with rows.

Below is my code for p-table :

```
<p-table [columns]="columns" [value]="values" [(selection)]="selectedRowData"
                 [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200px">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-gridColumns>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3em">
                        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                    </th>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of gridColumns">
                        {{col.header}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-gridColumns="columns">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
                    </td>
                    <td *ngFor="let col of gridColumns" style="word-break: break-all; max-width: 100px;">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

can someone help me aligning the headers with its row?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and in my scenario it was resolved by adding `[scrollable]="true"` after `scrollHeight` and add width to columns. like

```
<p-table [columns]="columns" [value]="values" [(selection)]="selectedRowData" [responsive]="true" 
                scrollHeight="248px" scrollDirection="both" [autoLayout]="true" [scrollable]="true">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-gridColumns>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3em">
                        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 100vw;" *ngFor="let col of gridColumns">
                        {{col.header}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-gridColumns="columns">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 3em">
                        <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
                    </td>
                    <td *ngFor="let col of gridColumns" style="width: 100vw !important; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

Note:

- Data is displayed as ellipsis after 100vw
- Width on `th` accordingly same as on `td`

Comment: style="width: 100vw" on th & td fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: @luke.mas Sounds good :)

Comment: Would would only work if the table has 2 columns btw.

Comment: @OussamaEssamadi you should add the exact width of the table index of td and th; columns do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my resolution had part of the previous answers but also required `min-width` to be set. Yours may work without the `min-width` but mine required it to function properly. We are on PrimeNG `"primeng": "11.3.1",`

Working example:

```
#idOfPTableElement {
  th {
    width: 100vw !important;
    min-width: 210px;
  }

  td {
    width: 100vw !important;
    min-width: 210px;
  }
}
```

Relative to this topic/issue, the header and the body of the p-table are separate tables. In addition, I had to use the following to fix the body *(actual table data section/body)* alignment issues I experienced. Without it, the lower table was indented looking and was never in alignment with the upper table (header table)

```
  .p-datatable-scrollable-header-box {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a bug from primeng end, when scrollable height is added to p-table tag and more no.of rows are there then this issue occurs.
When only one row then this issue is not there.

SOLUTION:
Instead of using scrollable and scroll height, add height to the parent tav of the table. With the below mentioned approach I am able to resolve alignment issues.

Eg:`

```
<div style ="max-height:60vh;overflow:auto">
<p-table></p-table>
</div>
```

`